# Django-CMS starting page

Tags: django-cms

When installing django-CMS, you are given the option of

```
Load a starting page with examples after installation: yes/no
```

And if you choose yes, then you get a nice starting page that you can immediately start editing to create your website. But what if you select no, how do you start then? Is there a way to retroactively add this starting page after accidentally selecting no? I could reinstall the entire project, but I really, really don't want to.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I think this is a relevant question for people like me who are a. beginners in Django b. beginners in Django-CMS. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course the answer is simple. The django admin site is still available through

`nameofyoursite.com/admin`

so just go there and create a new page object, which will later be available through the site.